# Allow users to draw their own route

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

We are using Mapbox SDK iOS.  We are wondering if there is a way to allow users to draw their own routes and save them.  These routes will be for walking and will allow users to create their own routes.  I've read a little about BYOR but there is little documentation about how to implement this.